# Is Xamarin open source?

Tags: xamarin

I do not know if [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) is open source or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet.  As part of the acquisition by Microsoft, they announced plans to open the codebase, but it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Time for an [update](https://github.com/xamarin)? *Xamarin is an open-source platform for building modern and performant applications for iOS, Android, and Windows with .NET* taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin)